# Execute maven goal in command line with phase as parameter

Tags: maven, maven-3

I want to run a maven plugin goal using command line. This plugin is not defined in my `pom` and for this reason can not specify the phase with configuration. Even so, maven is able to find it in the repo and execute the goal properly. The problem is that these goals are executed in the order they appear in the command line, is there a way to link this goal to a specific phase with a command line parameter? I'm looking for something like:

`mvn org.something:plugin-name:1.0.0:plugin-goal -phase=test package`

This would execute all the phases before `package` and in the `test` phase, my goal would be executed? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The way to solve this problem is to add the plugin to the POM and specify the execution in the phase `test`.